# Using Pandas to calculate December-January-February average

Tags: python, pandas, time-series

I want to use Pandas to calculate the average of three values over three separate months in a dataset which lists the year, month and value of interest in three different columns. Normally, I would just use pandas.loc and isin() and panads.groupby functions to do this, but one of the seasons I want to analyze is December-January-February which will go across two separate years of data (i.e. Dec. 2000, Jan. 2001, Feb. 2001). Wondering if anyone has any suggestions on how to deal with this type of thing.

```
2000  1  5
2000  2  6
2000  3  8
2000  4  10
2000  5  9
2000  6  11
2000  7  13
2000  8  6
2000  9  8
2000  10 7
2000  11 7
2000  12 4
2001  1  3
2001  2  5
```

(i.e. In this situation, Jan. and Feb. 2000 would be ignored, averages would be MAM: 9, JJA: 10, SON: 7.33, DJF: 4)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can define custom quarters and use `groupby`

```
# Test data
df = pd.DataFrame({'month': [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 1, 2],
                   'year': [2000, 2000, 2000, 2000, 2000, 2000, 2000, 2000, 2000, 2000, 2000, 2000, 2001, 2001],
                   'value': [5.0, 6.0, 8.0, 10.0, 9.0, 11.0, 13.0, 6.0, 8.0, 7, 7, 4, 3.0, 5.0]})

# Custom quarters definition
quarters = {1: 'DJF', 2: 'DJF', 3: 'MAM', 4: 'MAM', 5: 'MAM', 6: 'JJA', 7: 'JJA', 8: 'JJA', 9: 'SON', 10: 'SON', 11: 'SON', 
    12: 'DJF'}

df = df.set_index(['month'])

# can be grouped by year and quarters
df.groupby(['year',quarters])['value'].mean()

year     
2000  DJF     5.000000
      JJA    10.000000
      MAM     9.000000
      SON     7.333333
2001  DJF     4.000000

# or only by quarters according to the needs
df.groupby(quarters)['value'].mean()

DJF     4.600000
JJA    10.000000
MAM     9.000000
SON     7.333333
```

Comment: I don't think this is correct. You want the mean "across two separate years". The method outlined here gives you the mean of Jan-Feb and Dec of the same year. How can you get the mean of Dec 2000 and Jan-Feb 2001?

Answer (score 1):

I think what you're looking for is the `rolling_mean`.

For example,

```
ts
Out[39]:
2000-01-31   -1.782781
2000-02-29    0.976542
2000-03-31   -1.932712
2000-04-30    0.098827
2000-05-31   -0.236521
2000-06-30   -0.869157
2000-07-31    0.653783
2000-08-31    0.341896
2000-09-30   -0.685596
2000-10-31   -1.126368
2000-11-30    0.850350
2000-12-31   -1.583704
2001-01-31    1.677160
2001-02-28    1.872733
Freq: M, dtype: float64
```

providing a window of 3

```
pd.rolling_mean(ts,3)
Out[40]:
2000-01-31         NaN
2000-02-29         NaN
2000-03-31   -0.912983
2000-04-30   -0.285781
2000-05-31   -0.690135
2000-06-30   -0.335617
2000-07-31   -0.150632
2000-08-31    0.042174
2000-09-30    0.103361
2000-10-31   -0.490023
2000-11-30   -0.320538
2000-12-31   -0.619907
2001-01-31    0.314602
2001-02-28    0.655396
Freq: M, dtype: float64
```

this calculates overlapping ranges as well, which you can ignore.

Answer (score 0):

Add a new column that makes a "month ID" from the existing data, with a value such as (year - 2000)*12 + (month - 2).  Then just group by this new value.